# ReactJS cannot display image from backend folder using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm new in React.js and I have some data (actions) coming from database. Every action has an array of images.

I cannot display the images in image tag. Images are stored in a the backend folder structure like below:

[image: folders]

I was reading some questions and tried to use `express.static()` but it didn't work for me:

server.ts

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const routes = require('./routes');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/uploads/actions', express.static('uploads/actions'));
app.use(routes);

app.listen(3000);
```

frontend

```
{
    topicData.map((topic) => (
        <div className="topic-data" key={topic.id}>
            <div className="title">
                <p>{topic.title}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="description">
                <p>{topic.description}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="media">
                {topic.images.map((image) => (
                    <img key={image.id} src={"/uploads/actions/" + image.image} alt="file" />
                ))}
            </div>
            <div className="contribute-btn">
                <button onClick={() => contributions()}>Add comments</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    ));
}
```

I tried usgin `<img key={image.id} src={"http://localhost:3333/uploads/actions/" + image.image} alt="file" />` but it didn't work too. What should be the correct "react way" of doing this?

Comment: Looks like your folder `uploads/` isn't in the same directory as your `server.ts`, so your server can't serve those images.

Comment: Did you got any answer ? am also stuck in this place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you serving your react app with the express or you are using webpack-dev-server/create-react-app? If your front-end is served from a different port (ex. 4000) you should specify the absolute path as you did. However, you will get the cors error and it will be necessary to enable it with cors middleware: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html The second option is to use proxy to run backend and frontend on the same domain.

Comment: Yes. Frontend is running on 3000 and backend in 3333. I specified the absolute path (http://localhost:3333/uploads/actions/ + image.image) but no images are displayed

Comment: pasting in browser the absolute path I get this error `Cannot GET /uploads/actions/1616437561024-foto54.jpg`

Comment: request to http://localhost:3333/uploads/actions/1616437561024-foto54.jpg returns you 404 error, right?

Comment: oh, I see. From your project structure it should be the correct path: app.use('/uploads/actions', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../uploads/actions')));

Comment: I did that based on @boolfalse answer. But it does not work :(

Comment: Should I change anything in `img` tag?

Comment: with '..' at the beginning of the path? that's important here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230238/discussion-between-denis-malykhin-and-madsongr).

Comment: It's done! It was missing "..". Sorry and thank you so much!!

Comment: I'm having this issue also but can't find a way to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You could just create a folder like uploads instead of nesting actions in uploads folder.
You can then view the image in the browser through this url
[localhost:3333/uploads/1616437561024-foto54.jpg](https://localhost:3333/uploads/actions/1616437561024-foto54.jpg)

```
// Function to serve all static files
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
app.use('/uploads/actions', express.static('uploads/actions'));
```

use this:

```
// don't forget to require the "path" module before that
const path = require('path');

app.use('/uploads/actions', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads/actions')));
```

Actually with [**path.join(...)**](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) you'll mention the full path of your image file.

Comment: Ok. Still not displaying images. Should I change anything in `img` tag?